Bipolar inverter
Here is a circuit using TTL logic:

I wanted to determine the high and low state of the input and output voltage.
In saturation, for this exercise we will consider VCE = 0.2 V and VBE = 0.8 V
My problem is that I don't know how to solve these kind of problems.
The teacher gave us the Voh and Vol:
For Voh;
The transistor is bloqued => Ic = 0. Then no voltage drop through the Rc resistor.
Then: Voh = Vdd = 5 V.
For VOL: Q1 is in saturation => Vol = VCE = 0.2 V
However, I do not understand how he proceeded to write that.
And now, what to do for Vil and Vih?

Did the problem state the beta of the transistor and the voltage definitions of "high" and "low"?

If the initial assumptions for the transistor state that the Vce is 0.2V and Vbe is 0.8V in saturation, then it also implies that when you turn the transistor on so hard that it's in saturation, it will have the assumed 0.2V over Vce and 0.8V over Vbe. It is difficult to understand what about this is unclear and why. If you have an assumed beta of the transistor, you can calculate the currents and voltages at input that end up to the given output values.

Imagine another inverter input connected to the output scrutinised: What is Voh now?

@justme - I am afraid it would help to have some information about the beta of the transistor. Don`t forget that there is an additional remarkable portion of Ib which goes through the base-collector junction. So we will NOT be able to "calculate the currents and voltages at input that end up to the given output values."

At first, let us recall the definition of saturation:
A transistor (npn) is in saturation when the potential Vc at the collector is lower than the base potential: Vc<Vb or Vce<Vbe .
As a consequence, the B-E junction is forward biased and - in addition to the "normal" base current to the emitter - there is an additional current into the base which goes to the collector.
Therefore, the total base current Ib is much larger than anticipated by the classical relation Ib=Ic/B.
For further calculation, we start with selecting a collector current: For Vdd=5V and Rc=1k a value of app. Ic=5mA is sufficient.
When the resistor between Vin and the base is fixed with 10kOhms the value of Vin depends on the base current Ib drawn by the two forward biased pn junctions. But we have no good estimate for this current Ib.
Therefore, to be on the safe side (and when we have no further information), it is common practice to use a value for Ib which is app. between (5...10)% of Ic.
Using, for example, a value of Ib=0.25mA, the required input voltage can be found from Vin=Ib*10k+0.8V=2.5+0.8)=3.3V.
Comment: It is not possible to exactly design this circuit to comply with the mentioned values VCE=0.2 V and VBE=0.8 V. This is because we cannot predict an exact value for Ic and we do not have any information about the actual base current Ib.
